# Let $A$ be a set and $x>0$ integer. What is $x^A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set and $x>0$ integer. What is $x^A$? or can we define such a set?

As an example: $2^A$ is power set of $A$. What is $3^A$ or any $x^A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^A=\{f:A\longrightarrow  \{0,...,x-1\}\}$$

Comment: Easy question. Thanks.